# Convergence of a complex serie

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $\partial$$\mathcal{D}$ = {$\mathcal{z}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ : $\vert$$\mathcal{z}$$\vert$ = 1}. Prove that for $\mathcal{a_n}$ = $\frac 1n$, the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$\mathcal{a_n}$$\mathcal{z^n}$ is 1, and the series converges for every $\mathcal{z}$ $\in$ $\partial$$\mathcal{D}$$\setminus${1}

I already managed to do the first part of the assignment, but I am still having difficulties about the second part on the convergence of the series, I have thought about using the direct comparison test, the Weierstrass M-Test, or the Leibniz criterion, without success.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Note: "Series" is singular and plural. We do not say "serie"  to mean one series.

Comment: Sorry, my bad!  I edited it

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: Try Abel's test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z\in \partial \mathcal{D}\setminus\{1\}$, then $z = \exp(2\pi i t)$ for some $t\notin \Bbb Z$. Show that the partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty z^n$ satisfy

$$\left\lvert \sum_{n = 1}^N z^n\right\rvert \le \frac{1}{\lvert\sin(\pi t)\rvert}$$
for all $N$. (Note $\sin(\pi t)\neq 0$ since $t$ is not an integer.) Deduce from the Dirichlet test that the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty a_n z^n$ converges.